# Mvc Render Action/Partial to Response Output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.renderpartial

Although `@Html.RenderPartial` calls write and returns `void`, it is still writing to a `StringWriter`/`StringBuilder`.  Is there a way to render directly to the `ResponseStream`?

Can this be done with a custom `IViewEngine` that implements render like `PdfView` to directly output to the `ResponseStream`?

**ADDITION**

`ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult` shows the `ViewContext` being built with `Response.Output`, but debugger shows `ViewContext.Writer` as a `StringWriter`

Both of these approaches results in a `StringWriter`

```
return PartialView("view", Model)
// or
PartialView("view", Model).ExecuteResult(ControllerContext)
```

**EDIT**

It appears that `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase` `ExecutePageHeirarchy` pushes a temp `StringWriter` onto the context stack, so I'm not sure if this can be bypassed

**IN SUMMARY**

RenderPartial, RenderAction do not directly output to the Response.Stream, none of Razor Views will

**SOLUTION**

It was the new WebPages/Razor rendering engine that wraps everything with a `StringWriter` to a `StringBuilder`.   The solution was to change my page to use the  `WebFormViewEngine` which does not apply this wrapping.

Comment: Instead of updating the answer with solution, It would be more convenient for users seeking similar problem if you add solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This below method illustrates one way achieving the outcome you are looking for:

```
// <summary>
// An extension methods for rendering a model/view into a stream
// </summary>
// <param name="myModel">The model you are trying render to a stream</param>
// <param name="controllerBase">This will come from your executing action</param>
// <returns></returns>
        public static Stream GetStream(CustomModel myModel, ControllerBase controllerBase)
        {
            //we will return this stream
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            //you can add variables to the view data
            controllerBase.ViewData["ViewDataVariable1"] = true;

            //set your model
            controllerBase.ViewData.Model = myModel;

            //The example uses the UTF-8 encoding, you should change that if you are using some other encoding.
            //write to a stream
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                using (var sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    //render the view  ~/Views/Shared/_FeedbackMessage.cshtml (can be passed in as a parameter if you want to make it super generic)
                    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerBase.ControllerContext, "_FeedbackMessage");

                    //create a new view context
                    var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerBase.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controllerBase.ViewData, controllerBase.TempData, sw);

                    //Render the viewengine and let razor do its magic
                    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);    
                    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controllerBase.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);

                    //get StringBuilder from StringWriter sw and write into the stream writer
                    //you could simply return the StringWriter here if that is what you were interested in doing
                    writer.Write(sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString());

                    writer.Flush();

                    stream.Position = 0;
                }

            }

            //return the stream from the above process
            return stream;
        }
```

Comment: This is no different then ViewResultBase.  My goal is to output directly to Response.Output and to not capture it in a StringBuilder.   - The issue is not with MVC, but with the System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase which wraps the call into a new wrapped StringWriter.  - My end solution was to use to WebFormViewEngine which does allow for direct output to the response stream